# How to get the data from upload file in java script?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the data from fileupload, for example I want to get the data from .txt file, remove duplicates in the file and display in textbox(with out duplicates)

My snippet is:

```
 function m1(file,target) {
    var file = document.getElementById("fup1").value;
    var input= file.trim().replace(';', ',').split(',');
     var distinctArray = input.filter(function (val) {
       return input.indexOf(val) ==-1;
    });
    target.value = distinctArray.join(',');
}
```

My controls are:

```
 <table>
<tr>
<td> <asp:FileUpload ID="fup1" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit" onclick='m1(<%=fup1.ClientID%>,<%=txt1.ClientID%>);return false;' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm not getting anything, can you help please?

Comment: Have you checked [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) about reading files using **FileReader**?

Comment: i want to get the data from upload file....